# PHP checking if csv file exists?

Tags: php, csv, fopen, overwrite, fputcsv

The problem with this code is that each time I export from MySQL to csv  it overwrites the already created csv. I want this code to check if there is an already created csv file -> create new one. Ex. (Sales-2012-9-8.csv) to (Sales1-2012-9-8.csv)...This code works great on exporting records from MySQL..But when it comes to export another csv it overwrites the current csv file name.

Oh yea, one more thing..How is it possible to add Table Headers at the first row of csv file. Ex ( Item No - Qty - Selling Price - Date )?

Thank You

```
<?php
require_once('connect_db.php');
$fdate = $_POST['fdate'];
$tdate = $_POST['tdate'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_no, qty, discount_price, date FROM sold_items WHERE date BETWEEN '".$fdate."' AND '".$tdate."' ORDER BY date Desc");

$filename = $name = "Sales";
$index = 1;
while(file_exists($filename)) {
  $filename = $name.$index;
  $index++;
  echo "File Already Exists";
}

if(!$f = fopen("E:/{$filename}-{$tdate}.csv", 'w')){
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert('USB FLASH NOT INSERTED');
    history.back();
    </script>
    <?php
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    fputcsv($f, $row);
}

fclose($f);


?>
<center><font style="font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; color:#C00;">USB Transfer Successful</font></center> 
<center><input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.close()" value="Close Window" /></center>
<?php

?>
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Please give the error messages or a more detialed description on what exactly isn't working

Comment: Read about SQL Injection and fix your code. You close file no matter if `fopen()` succeeded.

Comment: off topic but important: The `mysql_xxx()` function are considered obsolete and should not be used. The PHP manual recommends switching to either the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions, or the PDO library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this variant. I think file_exists() function see into other folder than "E:/":

```
$tdate = date();
$filename = $name = "Sales";
$index = 1;
while(file_exists("E:/{$filename}-{$tdate}.csv")) {
  $filename = $name.$index;
  $index++;
  echo "File {$filename}-{$tdate}.csv Already Exists";
}

if(!$f = fopen("E:/{$filename}-{$tdate}.csv", 'w')){
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert('USB FLASH NOT INSERTED');
    history.back();
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

As for the second question:

> Oh yea, one more thing..How is it possible to add Table Headers at the first row of csv file. Ex ( Item No - Qty - Selling Price - Date )?

As I know, the first line of a csv-file is recognized as headers. So, try write your headers before writing the query results. E.g.

```
fputcsv($f, array('Item No', 'Qty', 'Selling Price', 'Date'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking the filename with the value "Sales" - The date isn't included yet!

Comment: Ok, I've tested it like this ( $filename = $name = "Sales-{$tdate}"; ) and the exported csv name is (Sales-2012-09-08-2012-09-08.csv) And Even on  exporting again, it overwrites the current csv file. Its like $index=1 is not currently working.

Comment: Of course you'll also have to include the filetype (.csv) otherwise the filename won't be correct.

Comment: Okay again , Tested ( $filename = $name = "Sales-{$tdate}.csv"; ) is still not working :( ! I appreciate your help.

Comment: And you're overwriting the "Sales-{$tdate}.csv" with "Sales-{$tdate}.csv1" in the first loop, but then you're using the filename "Sales-{$tdate}.csv1-{$tdate}.csv. So the file "Sales-{$tdate}.csv1" doesn't exist after all - You're just not using the same name when writing the file.